# Meteor.call to return some documents from a collection

Tags: meteor

This code is trying to display items from a collection via a method call to prevent client from changing the query selection in the `collection.find` options.

**edit**
The reason there is a "group" field is that later the server will change the group and the items for the menu will be expected to change to reflect the new group.

Why am I getting no items displayed and how to fix it? Thanks

```
///////////////////////////
//   client/client       //
///////////////////////////
<template name="mainMenu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group menuItems">
          {{#each menuItems}}
            <li data-template="{{menuItem}}" role="presentation">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item menuItem">
                <img src="/abc.png">
                {{menuItem}} <span class="badge">&#x3e;</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Template.mainMenu.helpers({
  menuItems: function () {
    return Meteor.call('getMenuItems');
  }
});

/////////////////////////////////////
//       server side code
/////////////////////////////////////
var items =
  [
    {menuItem: "task1",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task2",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task3",group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task4",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task5",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task6",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "task7",group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task8",group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "task9",group: "b"},
    {menuItem: "login",group: "a"},
    {menuItem: "logout",group: "a"}
  ]
_.each(items, function (doc) {
  MenuItems.insert(doc);
})

Meteor.methods({
    getMenuItems: function () {
            return MenuItems.find({group: 'a'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Why such a convoluted approach? What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: if 'MenuItems.find({group: 'a'});' is returned then a user can change to group: 'b' in browser console which is something the server will later change at well.  Isn't that right?

Comment: It's easier to control what menus are published from the server-side publication. Only send to the client what is legitimate. Using Meteor.call() for what you're trying to do is an anti-pattern.

Comment: i don't think it is anti-pattern @MichelFloyd. IMO, you use `publish` when you want to have sth reactive. otherwise, just make a normal classic `request-return`

Comment: I gonna change my answer. With the update, my answer is not correct anymore

Comment: Easier to do `find({},{reactive: false})` in the helper on the client to prevent reactivity client-side.

Comment: yup, that is correct. I just found it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
return Meteor.call('getMenuItems');
```

is not the correct syntax to get the data from server. You need to use a callback and set it to a reactive var in order to display to the template

Secondly, calling to server from the helpers is wrong (in this case). The calling need to be triggered from the `onRendered`

```
Template.mainMenu.onRendered = function() {
    Meteor.call('getMenuItems', function(err, res) { 
        Session.set('menuItems', res);
    });
}

Template.mainMenu.helpers({
    menuItems: function () {
       return Session.get('menuItems');
    }
});
```

**Update**
With the updated question, since you want the reactive on the menu, data need to be retrieved by using publication like @MichelFloyd mentioned in the comment.

Change your template to

```
Template.mainMenu.onCreated = function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('menuItems', 'a');  
}



Template.mainMenu.helpers({
    menuItems: function () {
        return MenuItems.find();
    }
});
```

and remove the `Meteor.call`. On your server, make a publication

```
Meteor.publish('menuItems', function(group) {
   return MenuItems.find({group: group});
});
```

Comment: Isn't storing the documents in a session an overkill since they are already available in the  collection? Plus "note my edit" The group will be changed at well by the server later to make different items available for the menu.;) Would you solution still be optimum? thx

Comment: Thai: What would stop the client from doing 'Meteor.subscribe('menuItems', 'b');' i.e. change the subscription options, the since this code is on the client side? And how can the same be done later by the server on demand?

Comment: it depends on your context, @FredJ. I just made it flexible for the client to easier to subscribe. You may filter based on the user on the publication and send back the correct data. Just remove the filter on the client would be fine

Answer (score 0):

The method is asynchronous and can only return data via a callback which needs to be declared after any variables you pass the method

*Option 1 - Session variables*

```
Meteor.call ('my-method', var1, ..., varx, function (err, data){      
if (err)         
   console.log (err);       
else          
   Session.set('method-data', data);    
});
```

Then you can just use the session var in the template helper and as soon as the method returns your helper will rerender.

*Option 2 - Reactive vars*

If you don't want to pollute the session  you can always use the reactive-var package to set a reactive variable on the template as below you will need to add the reactive var package first

`meteor add reactive-var`

Then in your template created function declare a reactive var attached to `self` which is set to `this` (the template instance itself). Call the method and use `self` in the callback to set the reactive var.

```
var self = this;
self.methodData = new ReactiveVar(false); 
Meteor.call('my-method', function (err, data) {  
   if (err) 
      console.log(err); 
   else 
      self.methodData.set(data);
 });
```

You can reference this in your helper with

`return Template.instance().methodData.get();`

Comment: Bummer totally missed the edit pub/sub answer much better for this scenario